# how to Make a NFC tag unreadable with other readers?

Tags: security, tags, nfc, access-control

I have read in many areas how to make the NFC information unreadable with another applications, but incase if we are using NFC stickers, how to make these stickers to be unreadable with other readers, so that no one can clone my NFC sticker?,

My other question is, If the NFC sticker is encrypted what are the chances that some one can clone it as well?

Comment: Can you share links of your readings?

Answer (score 2):

### Cloning

If you use an NFC tag (as defined by the [NFC Forum](http://nfc-forum.org/our-work/specifications-and-application-documents/specifications/tag-type-technical-specifications/)), there is not really a way to prevent them from being cloned. These NFC tags are world-readable by design.

You could, however, sign your data in combination with some information that is unique for every tag (e.g. at least NFC Forum type 1 and type 2 tags typically contain a unique serial number). Nevertheless, you should keep in mind that some of these serial numbers (particularly 4 byte UIDs) are not really unique. Moreover, if someone really want's to duplicate your NFC tag, there are (inexpensive, but more complex) ways to clone the tag including the UID.

Besides NFC tags, there exist some other NFC-compatible tags/smartcards which can provide more sophisticated countermeasures against cloning (e.g. DESFire EV1 and FeliCa (when used to their full extent and not only as NFC tags), JavaCard, etc).

### Reading with only your app

Again, with NFC tags, you cannot really prevent any other application from reading the data off the tag. However, you can prevent the application from being able to interpret the data by means of encryption.

And again, smartcards/tags with more than NFC tag capabilities might provide this partially out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Unreadable to other readers is really a relative term. You want to be asking whether tags can be protected with a password and whether that password can be obtained by others in real-life scenarios.

- Mifare Ultralight (C) tags can be read by others (including NTAG 203)
- Mifare Classic tags can be protected by a password, however this is broken by an advanced user (in zero time)
- Mifare Desfire EV1 can be protected by encryption

There are new types of tags coming, so you might want to look into that, but they will be relatively more expensive.